# Color indicator for page rating fraction decimal value at Jekyll pages

Tags: ruby, hex, jekyll, indicator, generate

Every articles of my site based on Jekyll are rated with some formula and have values in fraction decimals from 0.0 either 179.87 and further more. Here is sample of the including in layout

```
<p class="one">#<u><a 
href="https://www.google.com?q={{ page.shortname 
}}">{{ page.shortname }}</a></u> {% include 
indexmod.html %}</b><br>is an Indexmod of the “{{ 
page.title }}”<br> at the <a href="index">{{ 
site.title }}</a><br>{{ site.time | 
date_to_long_string }}</p>
```

that displays on the [random page sample](https://indexmod.gq/amed-imran) an article rating some value (here 179.87) in fraction decimal value. I want to generate and include with a color indicator that getting a hex color value from any fraction decimal value and look like correspondent-color-dot (see below)

[image: Mockup]

Comment: What does that color represent?

Comment: In theory this is abstract display of sort of karma, in real is the high of the rating (see full rating formula here https://indexmod.gq/indexmod) from white 0.0 to green or red of the highest rate value. Later I want to clarify rating color with age and some other values as facebook or youtube rates correlation. In ideal way this should be any hex color from hex palette in 3D including third one as brightness.